# Floored and Euclidean division of big integers

Tags: java, biginteger, integer-division

Java's BigInteger class provides truncated division (quotient and remainder). Given this as a starting point, what's the simplest and most efficient way to implement floored and Euclidean division (quotient and remainder)?

Comment: What exactly you after? Why dont you use BigDecimal?

Comment: To clarify, you want the result to round toward negative infinity, not toward zero?

Comment: @SMA I'm implementing the TPTP specification for first-order logic with arithmetic, which prescribes all three kinds of integer division. BigDecimal solves a different problem, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yes, as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102423/efficiently-implementing-floored-euclidean-integer-division

Comment: Have a look at Guava's [BigIntegerMath.divide](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/math/BigIntegerMath.html#divide(java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.RoundingMode))

Comment: Can you not do something along the lines dividing and if the result isn't an integer, take the integer part, and correct negative numbers as needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the answer of [Soronbe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4701236/soronbe), here are the implementations (excluding the second variant of floored divison) in correct Java syntax:

```
public BigInteger euclidianDivision(BigInteger a, BigInteger b) {
    return
        a.subtract(
            a.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) < 0 ?
                b.subtract(BigInteger.ONE) :
                    BigInteger.ZERO
        ).divide(b)
}

public BigInteger flooredDivision(BigInteger a, BigInteger b) {
    return
        a.add(
            (a.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) < 0) != (b.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) < 0) ?
                b.subtract(BigInteger.ONE) :
                    BigInteger.ZERO
        ).divide(b);
}
```

**Update:**
For computing the remainder according to the three division algorithms, two of them are already implemented in `BigInteger` (`mod` for the Euclidean division and `remainder` for the truncating division). To obtain the remainder for flooring division, you can use the following implementation:

```
public BigInteger flooredRemainder(BigInteger a, BigInteger b) {
    return
        a.mod(b).subtract(
            b.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) < 0 ? BigInteger.ONE : BigInteger.ZERO
        );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4110620/4701236 this should be quite efficient. Note this is tested for efficiency in C and not Java, yet seeing the differences are rather small, I dont expect them to be big in Java (differences between implementations, not between C and Java) as the current Java compiler optimizes a lot.

```
public BigInteger euclidianDivision(BigInteger a,BigInteger b){
    return (a - (a<0 ? b-1 : 0)).divide(b)
}

public BigInteger flooredDivision(BigInteger a,BigInteger b){
    return (a + ( ((x<0) != (y<0))? b-1 : 0)).divide(b)
}

public BigInteger secondFlooredDivision(BigInteger a,BigInteger b){
    return (a + ( ((a ^ b) < 0)? b-1 : 0)).divide(b)
}
```

The secondFlooredDivision makes assumptions about the binary representation of negative number, so I advise you use the other. Currently not able to test this code, so if someone could run it and correct possible syntax mistakes (I wrote it as pseudo-code).