# Division without using '/' operator

Tags: c++, c, math, division, divide

I cannot use '/' and loops and I have to divide some numbers.
operands are 32-bit and I can't use recursion.

I thought of using shr but it only gives me 2^n divison and it also won't save the reminder.

any Ideas?

Comment: Division is just repeated subtraction.  Why can't you use the divide operator?

Comment: No loops. Does that mean recursion is on or off the table?

Comment: use the function `fmod() or div()`?

Comment: Perhaps some more specifics would help. What kind of datatypes can we assume need to be divided? uint32_t? int64_t?

Comment: You have nails and a fence, why can you not use a hammer?

Comment: C++ or C ? Please pick just one.

Comment: I cant use the divide operator because im working on closed system with limited memory. Recursion is off the table. The number is uint32. C language.

Comment: So.. how "no loops" is justified then?

Comment: @Domi any workaround is likely to take more memory than the regular divide operator ??!

Comment: @AlexG That's for sure... sounds like a made-up requirement or excuse...

Comment: Is the divisor a constant that is known at compile-time ?

Comment: Use a for loop?

Comment: @PaulR It is known, numbers like 27

Comment: @Dorni: in that case you can just use the [magic number method](http://www.hackersdelight.org/magic.htm), which requires only multiplication, addition and shift. Please hit the [edit] button and add all the relevant info from comments into your question, as people are getting frustrated by its vagueness.

Comment: Related question (possible duplicate): [Perform integer division using multiplication](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30790184/253056).

Comment: I consulted Mr Occam and he said its a badly-disguised homework question with artificial contraints applied by prof/TA.

Comment: Resembles https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   div_t output;

   output = div(27, 4);
   printf("Quotient part of (27/ 4) = %d\n", output.quot);
   printf("Remainder part of (27/4) = %d\n", output.rem);

   output = div(27, 3);
   printf("Quotient part of (27/ 3) = %d\n", output.quot);
   printf("Remainder part of (27/3) = %d\n", output.rem);

   return(0);
}
```

Output:

```
Quotient part of (27/ 4) = 6
Remainder part of (27/4) = 3
Quotient part of (27/ 3) = 9
Remainder part of (27/3) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this method based on magic numbers:
I implemented it based on this [link](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/128545-division-ten-magic-numbers.html)
It is usefull only with fixed divisor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here

    unsigned long MAX_NUM=1<<30; //Max num = 1073741824

    unsigned long num = 1073741824;
    unsigned long divisor=17;

    //unsigned long magic_num=round(double(MAX_NUM)/divisor);
    unsigned long magic_num = 63161284 // Fixed for divisor = 17

    unsigned long div = (num * magic_num) >> 30;
    unsigned long remain = num - div * divisor;

    cout << div << endl;
    cout << remain << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int a_div_b( int a, int b, int pow=0 ) {
  if (a<b) return 0;
  if (a < (b<<(pow+1)))
    return a_div_b(a-(b<<pow), b) + (1<<pow);
  return a_div_b(a, b, pow+1);
}
```

No loops, no `/`, `O((log(a/b))^2)` time. I could probably improve to `O(log(a/b))`, but I am lazy (recurse *down* from maximium pow once you find it, not back up).

Remainder can be easily calculated via `b-a_div_b(a,b)*a` without use of loops or `/`.

It should use O(1) memory as it is tail-end-recursive.

Comment: Good answer, but OP says in comments: "Recursion is off the table", which I take to mean "recursion is not allowed".

Comment: @PaulR I'm glad the OP has a different question.  He can press the "Ask Question" button to ask it.

Comment: Yes, the goalposts are moving pretty fast on this question!

Comment: I would say just unroll this for 32-bit unsigned values.

Comment: I think recursion will use a lot of memory with large numbers so i'm not supposed to use it.

Comment: @Dorni No, this uses O(1) memory assuming your compiler is not brain dead; it is tail-end recursive.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an academic exercise, they are probably wanting you to do:

a/b ::==  e**(log(a) - log(b))

Comment: OP claims this is for a resource-constrained system, apparently, so transcendental functions are probably going to be off-limits, I imagine.

Comment: And he want it with remainder. But I would rather close the question as unclear with such a requirements which do not align.

Comment: it seems like we are getting into impossibility now here.